# How get result in elasticsearch in PHP?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I use search query, where `$query` is string:

```
 $params = array();
 $params['body']['query']['match']['name'] = $query;
 $this->result = $this->client->search($params);
```

If do `var_dump($this->result)` after search:

```
array(4) {
  ["took"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timed_out"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["_shards"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["total"]=>
    int(12)
    ["successful"]=>
    int(12)
    ["failed"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["hits"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["total"]=>
    int(0)
    ["max_score"]=>
    NULL
    ["hits"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
}
```

I get array without information. Only system fields. How I can get result?

Comment: This isn't too helpful. What is the value of the $query variable and what data do you currently have indexed? The result you are seeing is probably correct

Comment: How I can see what data were indexed?

Comment: I mean the data that has been added to your elastic search instance? What I am basically saying is there are some easy ways to debug this. You can dump the $params array to make sure it is in the correct format and the the query $variable contains something that will be found. If the name doesn't match anything in your elastic search instance then the response is correct.

Comment: I have data in elsaticsearch, I checked

Comment: Are you sure any of that would match the query?

Comment: I found problem. Reason is that I use `match` type search instead `query string`

Comment: What type of search I need use if I want to find documets lik as it does LIKE in Mysql?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84744/discussion-between-babaev-and-david-jones).